# A* search in Prolog

Tags: search, prolog

I tried implementing a [15puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle) solver in prolog as a way to try and learn the language and take advantage of the native backtracking. I followed a few online [resources](https://www.cpp.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/5_1.html) and wrote this simple version of the A* algorithm.

All it does is generate all the children of a node and stick them at the end of a queue BFS style (eventually I intend to replace this with a priority queue for efficiency), and explores all the children, backtracking the solution with findall.

Relevant code:

```
solve(State,Soln) :- f_function(State,0,F),
                 search([State#0#F#[]],[],S), reverse(S,Soln).

search([State#_#_#Soln|_], All, Soln) :-
   goal(State).
search([B|R], All, S) :-
   gen(B, R, Children),
   %insert_all(Children,R,Open),     %insertion sort option
   append(R, Children, Open),        %naive option
   append(All, Children, Allnew),
   search(Open, Allnew, S).

gen(State#D#_#A, R,C) :-
   findall(Child#D1#F1#[Move|A],
         (  mover(State, Child, Move),
            D1 is D + 1,
            f_function(Child, D1, F1),
            \+member(Child, R)
         ), C).
```

This code finds the solution for simple initial configurations with only a few movements needed to reach the solution, but for more complex test cases, it doesn't halt.

To avoid infinite cycles, I keep a list All of all the states ever generated (even if they are already gone from the queue), and check my new children against that list before adding them.

If someone could tell me why this doesn't halt I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Try moving the test against `All` as early as possible; otherwise, it is too late to prevent any infinite loops.

Comment: @ScottHunter The test against All occurs at the gen call, and that's the first predicate I call on during search. Unless Im misunderstanding, It will check on the 2nd iteration of search, before appending the newly created cchildren, so that wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: If you say so; I don't know what `mover` or `f_function` do, but clearly *something* is preventing your query from halting.

Comment: mover is the function that applies a Move to a child to create a new child, and f_function is a heuristic function that isn't currently being used on the search. My gut tells me that the problem is in the A* part of the algorithm, but if it turns out what I posted isn't causing the issue, then I'l know exactly where to look for the problem

Comment: You didn't show how you call your predicate. But check the `append/3` calls. If either have two variables, they may be spinning off trying to find an endless number of solutions that eventually would fail. Also, by the way, `newAll` is an atom, not a variable. I assume that's a typo?

Comment: @lurker Added the predicate call. I believe both append calls only have one variable each (Open and Allnew), but I might have done something like that somewhere else that I can't see. Thanks for pointing that out, I changed the name in the post to make it more readable and forgot it couldn't be lowercase.

Comment: I don't see how the code as you are showing it would execute your second `search/3` clause. Assuming you call `solve(..., Soln)` first, it calls `search([State#0#F#[]],[],S)` which matches the first `search/3` clause, which will call `goal/1`. `goal/1` never calls `search/3` (unless it happens in `f_function/3` somewhere.

Comment: I thought it wouldn't match the first clause unless we already had the answer because goal(state) would evaluate to false..